# YUI 3 html templating

Tags: templating, yui3

Is there any way to create HTML markup in YUI like:

```
<div id={DivId}>
 <p class={pClass}>
  <span class={spanClass}> {Content} </span>
 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, [`Y.substitute`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/module_substitute.html) might be worth looking at.

If you haven't seen it, I'd recommend watching through the [YUI 3 Sugar](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=kloots-yuiconf2009-sugar) video at the [YUI theater](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/). Jump to 22:27 for more on `Y.substitute`.

Comment: There's also Y.Lang.sub(), Y.substitute's smaller, skinnier cousin. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/Lang.html#method_sub

Comment: Since this question was originally answered, YUI3 has also added built-in support for Handlebars templating: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/handlebars/

Comment: YUI 3.8.0 [introduced Y.Template](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2012/12/12/yui-3-8-0-y-color-templates-and-more/), which is faster than Handlebars, but offers more functionality than Y.Lang.sub and Y.substitute:

Comment: @Lauri Lehtinen can you tell me the jQuery equivalent of yui lang.sub function

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing.... Here is what I used.

```
var resultFormatTemplate =
        '<div class="result">{first_name}, {last_name}</div>';

function resultFormat(query, results) {
    return Y.Array.map(results, function (result) {
        var rep = result.raw;

        return Y.Lang.sub(resultFormatTemplate, {
            first_name : rep['First Name'],
            last_name  : rep['Last Name']
        });
    });
};
```

In the Y.one tag I used `resultFormatter  : resultFormat` to call the function.